# Are international withdrawals possible in São Tomé ATMs?

Tags: money, atms, sao-tome-and-principe

Is it possible to withdraw money from ATMs in São Tomé and Príncipe using international cards?

I saw news online of efforts as early as 2016 (pt-PT: [1](https://www.rfi.fr/pt/sao-tome-e-principe/20160826-sao-tome-e-principe-quer-adaptar-multibanco-internacional), [2](https://www.dinheirovivo.pt/economia/em-breve-podera-levantar-dinheiro-em-sao-tome-com-cartoes-internacionais-12847329.html)) to integrate the São-Tomé network with the VISA-network, but also news of April-2021 regarding [SIBS revamping the São-Tomé payment systems](https://www.sibs.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2021/04/270428_SIBS-interbank-payment-system-SaoTome-and-Principe_vf.pdf) which might mean that this internationalization is not finished yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

International withdrawals **are** possible, according to online news from late April 2021 (pt-PT):

https://www.telanon.info/economia/2021/04/26/34130/cartao-visa-ja-e-oficial-no-sistema-de-pagamento-automatico-de-stp/

According to Téla Nón, a digital São-Tomé news agency, the Executive Administrator of SPAUT (São Tomé Automatic Payment Systems of São Tomé and Príncipe) said (emphasis mine):

> o Sistema de Pagamentos Automáticos de S. Tomé e Príncipe **já está a aceitar a utilização de cartão VISA nos terminais ATM e POS** instalados em todo país e algumas pessoas já começaram a fazer as suas operações com o cartão VISA e com sucesso…

---

Translated:

> the Automatic Payments System of S. Tomé and Príncipe **is already accepting the use of VISA cards in the ATM and POS terminals** installed throughout the country, and some people have already successfully begun making their operations with VISA card…